# How to invoke a method of one component from the other [Angular]

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to web development. I'm working on an Angular project. I've two components, **filter-panel** and **filter-bar**. None of the them are parent-child to each other. I've checked some solution like:

[Access a method of one component from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60489837/access-a-method-of-one-component-from-another)

and many other solutions on the internet.

I tried two approaches:

1. @ViewChild
2. Service in angular

   But still I'm getting an error.

> ERROR TypeError: "_co.filterPanel is undefined"

Here's my code.

**filter-bar.component.html**

```
<button (click)="filterPanel.filterPanelMethod()">Call</button>
```

**filter-bar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterPanelComponent } from './filter-panel/filter-panel.component';
import { FilterPanelService } from './filter-panel/filter-panel.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-filter-bar',
    templateUrl: './filter-bar.component.html'
})
export class FilterBarComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild(FilterPanelComponent, {static : false}) public filterPanel: FilterPanelComponent;
   
    constructor(public filterPanelService: FilterPanelService) {      
      //filterPanelService.filterPanelMethod();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

**filter-panel.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FilterPanelService} from './filter-panel.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-filter-panel',
    templateUrl: './filter-panel.component.html'
})
export class FilterPanelComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public filterPanelService:FilterPanelService) {
    }

    filterPanelMethod() {
      console.log("I'm filter-panel method");
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

No data sending or receiving is involved here. I just want to see how the method is called and I'll take care of the rest. I'm sure I'm doing a terrible mistake somewhere. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-psvyt4) also. I'm afraid that I've mixed two approaches and got myself more confused. Please correct me.

Comment: Call a method of one child component from another child component.  I never found a solution to that.  Any insight ?  With providers of the called child inside the caller child seems to have access to the component but visually nothing happens as if the instance I have isn't the one I see on screen but a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put **FilterPanelComponent** inside of the **FilterBarComponent** view if you want to access it using **@ViewChild**. Now you are using both of them in the app component, that's why you can not access it. If you want to provide communication between them, I will propose you creating a service with **Subject** to which one of them will listen, and then take action when it will be expected.

Another solution but quite ugly is

1. Accessing `@ViewChild(FilterPanelComponent, {static : false}) public filterPanel: FilterPanelComponent;` inside of the **AppComponent**
2. Emit event from **FilterBarComponent** to **AppComponent** when button is clicked
3. Listen to that event In **AppComponent** and call method from **FilterPanelComponent**

Comment: I've changed my stackblitz can you see please

Comment: Look here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bptk9w?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffilter%2Ffilter-panel%2Ffilter-panel.service.ts

Comment: So `ViewChild` is no longer required.

Comment: If you use service, ViewChild is no longer required.

Comment: Ok then I'll use service only. Now I'll run some unit test cases and update you. However this solution worked and I'm accepting it. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the following two changes:

1. Invoke filter-panel from filter-bar.component.html

   ```
   <app-filter-panel></app-filter-panel>
   ```
2. Within filter-bar.component.ts you need to access the service reference using `this`. For eg:

   ```
    this.filterPanelService.someMethod();
   ```

Comment: But Sir they ain't supposed to be parent-child. Let's drop that approach. I was trying some solutions.

Comment: Why exactly can't they be parent child? Seems like an *XY* problem, which particular method do you want to invoke and what is the functionality behind it?

Comment: It's very complicated project. So i just tried to keep the things simple and thus created a stackblitz of the concept I wanted to learn.